# cmake finds custom OpenCV, ignores it

Tags: cmake, opencv3.0

I built OpenCV 3 on my system as it isn't provided by my package manager, but cmake still uses the system version.

As expected, when I leave `OpenCV_DIR` blank the following fails (because the system OpenCV is 2.4)

`FIND_PACKAGE(OpenCV 3 REQUIRED)`

When I `export OPENCV_DIR=/home/fruitcake/Desktop/opencvsrc/installed` the check passes, BUT the variable's get set to system OpenCV directory causing compile time errors.

For example: `OPENCV_CFLAGS` should be set to the prefix directory.

I assume there is something magical happening in `/OpenCVModules-release.cmake` but I can't figure how `OPENCV_CFLAGS` is set.

Whats the paradigmatic way to have a custom OpenCV search directory `OPENCV_CFLAGS`?

```
-- CONFIG_FILES=/home/fruitcake/Desktop/opencvsrc/installed/share/OpenCV/OpenCVModules-release.cmake
-- OPENCV_CFLAGS=-I/usr/include/opencv
-- OPENCV_INCLUDE_DIRS=/usr/include/opencv
-- OPENCV_LDFLAGS=/usr/lib64/libopencv_calib3d.so;/usr/lib64/libopencv_contrib.so;/usr/lib64/libopencv_core.so;/usr/lib64/libopencv_features2d.so;/usr/lib64/libopencv_flann.so;/usr/lib64/libopencv_gpu.so;/usr/lib64/libopencv_highgui.so;/usr/lib64/libopencv_imgproc.so;/usr/lib64/libopencv_legacy.so;/usr/lib64/libopencv_ml.so;/usr/lib64/libopencv_nonfree.so;/usr/lib64/libopencv_objdetect.so;/usr/lib64/libopencv_photo.so;/usr/lib64/libopencv_stitching.so;/usr/lib64/libopencv_superres.so;/usr/lib64/libopencv_ts.a;/usr/lib64/libopencv_video.so;/usr/lib64/libopencv_videostab.so;/usr/lib64/libXext.so;/usr/lib64/libX11.so;/usr/lib64/libICE.so;/usr/lib64/libSM.so;/usr/lib64/libGL.so;/usr/lib64/libGLU.so;-lrt;-lpthread;-lm;-ldl
-- OPENCV_LDFLAGS_OTHER=/usr/lib64/libopencv_calib3d.so;/usr/lib64/libopencv_contrib.so;/usr/lib64/libopencv_core.so;/usr/lib64/libopencv_features2d.so;/usr/lib64/libopencv_flann.so;/usr/lib64/libopencv_gpu.so;/usr/lib64/libopenc _highgui.so;/usr/lib64/libopencv_imgproc.so;/usr/lib64/libopencv_legacy.so;/usr/lib64/libopencv_ml.so;/usr/lib64/libopencv_nonfree.so;/usr/lib64/libopencv_objdetect.so;/usr/lib64/libopencv_photo.so;/usr/lib64/libopencv_stitching.so;/usr/lib64/libopencv_superres.so;/usr/lib64/libopencv_ts.a;/usr/lib64/libopencv_video.so;/usr/lib64/libopencv_videostab.so;/usr/lib64/libXext.so;/usr/lib64/libX11.so;/usr/lib64/libICE.so;/usr/lib64/libSM.so;/usr/lib64/libGL.so;/usr/lib64/libGLU.so
-- OPENCV_STATIC_CFLAGS=-I/usr/include/opencv
-- OPENCV_STATIC_INCLUDE_DIRS=/usr/include/opencv
-- OPENCV_STATIC_LDFLAGS=/usr/lib64/libopencv_calib3d.so;/usr/lib64/libopencv_contrib.so;/usr/lib64/libopencv_core.so;/usr/lib64/libopencv_features2d.so;/usr/lib64/libopencv_flann.so;/usr/lib64/libopencv_gpu.so;/usr/lib64/libopencv_highgui.so;/usr/lib64/libopencv_imgproc.so;/usr/lib64/libopencv_legacy.so;/usr/lib64/libopencv_ml.so;/usr/lib64/libopencv_nonfree.so;/usr/lib64/libopencv_objdetect.so;/usr/lib64/libopencv_photo.so;/usr/lib64/libopencv_stitching.so;/usr/lib64/libopencv_superres.so;/usr/lib64/libopencv_ts.a;/usr/lib64/libopencv_video.so;/usr/lib64/libopencv_videostab.so;/usr/lib64/libXext.so;/usr/lib64/libX11.so;/usr/lib64/libICE.so;/usr/lib64/libSM.so;/usr/lib64/libGL.so;/usr/lib64/libGLU.so;-lrt;-lpthread;-lm;-ldl
-- OPENCV_STATIC_LDFLAGS_OTHER=/usr/lib64/libopencv_calib3d.so;/usr/lib64/libopencv_contrib.so;/usr/lib64/libopencv_core.so;/usr/lib64/libopencv_features2d.so;/usr/lib64/libopencv_flann.so;/usr/lib64/libopencv_gpu.so;/usr/lib64/libopencv_highgui.so;/usr/lib64/libopencv_imgproc.so;/usr/lib64/libopencv_legacy.so;/usr/lib64/libopencv_ml.so;/usr/lib64/libopencv_nonfree.so;/usr/lib64/libopencv_objdetect.so;/usr/lib64/libopencv_photo.so;/usr/lib64/libopencv_stitching.so;/usr/lib64/libopencv_superres.so;/usr/lib64/libopencv_ts.a;/usr/lib64/libopencv_video.so;/usr/lib64/libopencv_videostab.so;/usr/lib64/libXext.so;/usr/lib64/libX11.so;/usr/lib64/libICE.so;/usr/lib64/libSM.so;/usr/lib64/libGL.so;/usr/lib64/libGLU.so
-- OPENCV_opencv_INCLUDEDIR=
-- OPENCV_opencv_LIBDIR=
-- OPENCV_opencv_PREFIX=
-- OPENCV_opencv_VERSION=
-- OpenCV_CONFIG=/home/fruitcake/Desktop/opencvsrc/installed/share/OpenCV/OpenCVConfig.cmake
-- OpenCV_CONSIDERED_CONFIGS=/home/fruitcake/Desktop/opencvsrc/installed/share/OpenCV/OpenCVConfig.cmake
-- OpenCV_DIR=/home/fruitcake/Desktop/opencvsrc/installed/share/OpenCV
-- OpenCV_FIND_COMPONENTS_=opencv_videostab;opencv_videoio;opencv_video;opencv_ts;opencv_superres;opencv_stitching;opencv_shape;opencv_photo;opencv_objdetect;opencv_ml;opencv_imgproc;opencv_imgcodecs;opencv_highgui;opencv_flann;opencv_features2d;opencv_cudev;opencv_cudawarping;opencv_cudastereo;opencv_cudaoptflow;opencv_cudalegacy;opencv_cudaimgproc;opencv_cudafilters;opencv_cudafeatures2d;opencv_cudacodec;opencv_cudabgsegm;opencv_cudaarithm;opencv_cuda;opencv_core;opencv_calib3d
-- OpenCV_INCLUDE_DIRS=/usr/include/opencv;/usr/include
-- OpenCV_LIBRARIES=opencv_videostab;opencv_videoio;opencv_video;opencv_ts;opencv_superres;opencv_stitching;opencv_shape;opencv_photo;opencv_objdetect;opencv_ml;opencv_imgproc;opencv_imgcodecs;opencv_highgui;opencv_flann;opencv_features2d;opencv_cudev;opencv_cudawarping;opencv_cudastereo;opencv_cudaoptflow;opencv_cudalegacy;opencv_cudaimgproc;opencv_cudafilters;opencv_cudafeatures2d;opencv_cudacodec;opencv_cudabgsegm;opencv_cudaarithm;opencv_cuda;opencv_core;opencv_calib3d
-- OpenCV_LIBS=opencv_videostab;opencv_videoio;opencv_video;opencv_ts;opencv_superres;opencv_stitching;opencv_shape;opencv_photo;opencv_objdetect;opencv_ml;opencv_imgproc;opencv_imgcodecs;opencv_highgui;opencv_flann;opencv_features2d;opencv_cudev;opencv_cudawarping;opencv_cudastereo;opencv_cudaoptflow;opencv_cudalegacy;opencv_cudaimgproc;opencv_cudafilters;opencv_cudafeatures2d;opencv_cudacodec;opencv_cudabgsegm;opencv_cudaarithm;opencv_cuda;opencv_core;opencv_calib3d
-- OpenCV_LIBS_DBG=opencv_videostab;opencv_videoio;opencv_video;opencv_ts;opencv_superres;opencv_stitching;opencv_shape;opencv_photo;opencv_objdetect;opencv_ml;opencv_imgproc;opencv_imgcodecs;opencv_highgui;opencv_flann;opencv_features2d;opencv_cudev;opencv_cudawarping;opencv_cudastereo;opencv_cudaoptflow;opencv_cudalegacy;opencv_cudaimgproc;opencv_cudafilters;opencv_cudafeatures2d;opencv_cudacodec;opencv_cudabgsegm;opencv_cudaarithm;opencv_cuda;opencv_core;opencv_calib3d
-- OpenCV_LIBS_OPT=opencv_videostab;opencv_videoio;opencv_video;opencv_ts;opencv_superres;opencv_stitching;opencv_shape;opencv_photo;opencv_objdetect;opencv_ml;opencv_imgproc;opencv_imgcodecs;opencv_highgui;opencv_flann;opencv_features2d;opencv_cudev;opencv_cudawarping;opencv_cudastereo;opencv_cudaoptflow;opencv_cudalegacy;opencv_cudaimgproc;opencv_cudafilters;opencv_cudafeatures2d;opencv_cudacodec;opencv_cudabgsegm;opencv_cudaarithm;opencv_cuda;opencv_core;opencv_calib3d
-- OpenCV_LIB_COMPONENTS=opencv_videostab;opencv_videoio;opencv_video;opencv_ts;opencv_superres;opencv_stitching;opencv_shape;opencv_photo;opencv_objdetect;opencv_ml;opencv_imgproc;opencv_imgcodecs;opencv_highgui;opencv_flann;opencv_features2d;opencv_cudev;opencv_cudawarping;opencv_cudastereo;opencv_cudaoptflow;opencv_cudalegacy;opencv_cudaimgproc;opencv_cudafilters;opencv_cudafeatures2d;opencv_cudacodec;opencv_cudabgsegm;opencv_cudaarithm;opencv_cuda;opencv_core;opencv_calib3d
-- _DIR=/home/fruitcake/Desktop/opencvsrc/installed/share/OpenCV
-- OPENCV_DIR: /usr/include/opencv
```

I am using cmake version 3.1.0

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I had to delete the `CMakeCache.txt`